# C#/CSS: Convert bytes to CSS hex string

Tags: c#, byte, hex

Let's say I have these `byte`s:

```
byte red = 0;
byte green = 0;
byte blue = 255;
```

And I want to turn it into the six-character string hex representation you see in CSS (e.g. "`#0000ff`"):

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
var hexColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(c);
```

should produce `"0000FF"`

[See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.tohtml.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Bala R is spot on for Windows Forms, but if you're using ASP.NET here's the quick-and-dirty way:

```
string cssColor = String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", red, green, blue);
```

Answer (score -1):

use

```
byte red = 0;
byte green = 0;
byte blue= 255;
byte[] color={red,green,blue};
string s = BitConverter.ToString(color);
```